# How could a c++ "function object" (functor) be defined in Clojure?

Tags: lambda, clojure, functional-programming, functor

By "c++ function object" (functor) I mean: "an object for which the function call operator is defined."

I guess there are several ways to do this. Just for instance, let's say we need a parameterized function:

```
f(x) = sin(x*freq) // maths
```

We could use "a function constructor":

```
(defn newSinus [freq] 
  (fn [x] (Math/sin (* freq x)))
)

(def sin1 (newSinus 2.0) )
(def sin2 (newSinus 1.5) )

(println (sin1 1.5))
(println (sin2 2.0))
```

But, what if we want to read the parameter in `sin1` or `sin2`?

How many ways we can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, that's it

Comment: A functor is something different - a way of lifting functions to other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but you can define a record that's callable as a function by satisfying the `clojure.lang.IFn` interface:

```
(defrecord Adder [x]
  clojure.lang.IFn
  (invoke [_ y]
    (+ x y)))

((->Adder 3) 4) ; => 7
```

Comment: Be careful, however, that the `fn?` predicate will return `false` for such an object. For this use case, I would question the design decision of having a function interface instead of an explicit protocol.

Answer (score 1):

(def adder (partial + 3))
(adder 4)

Also, creating a closure would do the same thing

(defn make-adder[x] (fn [y] (+ x y))

Answer (score 0):

From the answer by @exupero, I derive the following code for the "sinus" example.

```
;;
;; --- Sinus ---
;;    freq: R // state
;;    R -> constructor()
;;    R -> () -> R // this is invoke
;;    freq() -> R // getter, in fact it is freq: R
;; -------------
(defrecord Sinus [freq]
  ;;
  ;; implement this interface so Sinus 
  ;; appears as a "function object"
  ;;
  clojure.lang.IFn 
  (invoke [_ x]
    (Math/sin(* freq x))))

;; -----------------------------
;; "main()"
;; -----------------------------

;;
;; s1 <- new Sinus (2.5)
;;
(def s1 (Sinus. 2.5))

;;
;; s1.freq()
;;
(:freq s1) 

;;
;; s1(4)
;;
(s1 4)
```